# Jackson - Ignore attributes with specific name

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jersey

Is it possible to configure Jackson to ignore properties of objects based on the attribute name?

I'm serializing Hibernate entities with Jackson and every object on my JSON file comes with "hibernateLazyInitializer" attribute which i want to ignore. Also many classes have a "getFieldsValues" method which i want to ignore too.

I know i can use Jackson annotations to ignore certain attributes, but that would be much handwork. But in this case i need to IGNORE an attribute which is common to many objects and is being automatically parsed by Jackson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your update problem description in the comment, I'll try and give a better reference :

- Going with annotations is the cleanest way, as described in several posts relating to hibernate enhanced POJOs
- Something that might also satisfy would be setting this in the ObjectMapper, which should result in empty (but present) fields -
  `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);` . Maybe if you'll combine this with `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);`
    it might eliminate thos fields completely.
- Finally, an alternate (but bad) approach would be to modify Jackson's behavior by registering a module that applies an instance of `JsonSerializer<T>` for all types of your POJO. In that instance you'll to manually unset the fields from the created JsonNode created by using the defaultSerializer. Again, it's a bad idea.

Comment: I need to pass the attribute name to Jackson so that he can ignore it in any class he sees it.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus marking a field with a view annotation, you can have it excluded/included per serialization/deserialization request in specific scenarios (i.e. by passing the desired view to the ObjectMapper upon de/serialization). How does that not answer your needs ?

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus please expand on the issue a bit. Why do you care if this field gets deserialized.

And please "un-downvote" me  as I'm actually taking the time to try and help you.

Comment: I'm serializing Hibernate entities with Jackson and every object on my JSON file comes with hibernateLazyInitializer attribute which i want to ignore. I could annotate every class with @JsonIgnoreProperties but i have many classes and thought i could do it in a different way.


Also I didn't downvote you

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus OK got it. Basically Annotation/marking as transient is the cleanest way of doing that. I'll update my answer to better explain.